# UDP Sender program verification

Tags: c++, udp

I have wrote a simple program that is supposed to send UDP Packages with changing length. The sizes of UDP packets can change anytime.
The user can input through command line the port number and the minimum and maximum length of the message. At the first 32 bits of the payload is the UDP Packet Number.
I used the sendto() function and I am receiving a valid return number  but when I try to verify it using a UDP Server program (for example SocketTest) I cannot seeany data on the other end.
Following is my code :

```
#define DEFAULT_PORT 355

int   Port = DEFAULT_PORT;          // Port to send data to
int Max_Length = 100, Min_Length = 8; //default values
static const char alphanum[] =
    "0123456789"
    "!@#$%^&*"
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int stringLength = sizeof(alphanum);

char genRandom()
{
    return alphanum[rand() % stringLength];
}

void usage()
{
    cout << "-m:int Define minimum UDP packet size" << endl;
    cout << " -M:int Define maximum UDP packet size" << endl;
    cout << " -p:int Define remote port" << endl;

}

void ValidateArgs(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if ((argv[i][0] == '-'))
        {
            switch (argv[i][1])
            {
            case 'm':
                if (strlen(argv[i]) > 3) {
                    Min_Length = (double)atoi(&argv[i][3]);
                }
                break;
            case 'M':
                if (strlen(argv[i]) > 3) {
                    Max_Length = (double)atoi(&argv[i][3]);
                }
                break;
            case 'p':
                if (strlen(argv[i]) > 3) {
                    Port = atoi(&argv[i][3]);
                }                   
                break;
            default:
                usage();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    sockaddr_in my_addr;
    ValidateArgs(argc, argv);
    WSADATA wsd;
    int Result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsd);
    if (Result != NOERROR) {
        cout << "WSAStartup Failed!" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    SOCKET sock;
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        cout << "Socket Failer with error: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.68.0.31");
    my_addr.sin_port = htons((short)Port);
    string data = "";
    /*Get a Random String Length*/
    random_device seeder;
    int UDP_Packet_number = 1;
    string buffer_data;
    mt19937 engine(seeder());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(Min_Length, Max_Length);// user input from command line
    int StrLen = dist(engine);
    while (true) {
        /*Get aRandom String*/
        for (int i = 0; i < StrLen; ++i)
        {
            data += genRandom();

        }
        srand(time(0));
        StrLen = dist(engine);
        char numbr_pkg[4];
        numbr_pkg[0] = (UDP_Packet_number >> 24) & 0xff;
        numbr_pkg[1] = (UDP_Packet_number >> 16) & 0xff;
        numbr_pkg[2] = (UDP_Packet_number >> 8) & 0xff;
        numbr_pkg[3] = UDP_Packet_number & 0xff;
        /*First 32 Bits is the packet Number*/
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            buffer_data += numbr_pkg[i];
        }       

        buffer_data += data;
        data = "";
        int result = sendto(sock, buffer_data.c_str(), buffer_data.length(), 0, (SOCKADDR *)&my_addr, sizeof(my_addr));
        //cout << result << "  " << buffer_data.length() << endl;
        buffer_data = "";
        UDP_Packet_number++;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong? I am trying to find a solution for a long time.

Comment: What does "ψηανγινγ length" mean?

Comment: You're missing `}` at the end of the `main()` function.

Comment: You should use `unsigned int` with bit-shifting operations.

Comment: Are you seeing any packets at all at the other end?

Comment: Are you sure the destination address is correct? It's probably supposed to be `192.168`, not `192.68`.

Comment: @Barmar sorry i forgot to change the keyboard from my native language.I meant to say changing and i just forgot to copy paste the final '}' . I am not missing it .

Comment: @Barmar you are right about the destination adress. It works now. Stupid me.Thanks :)